# How do I make my Label Tkinter element display?

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently, I am creating a text adventure game. Now to make it a tiny bit better than a lot of them which use the python console, I am using Tkinter to make a GUI. Only it displays my background image for the start screen, but not the text I put there! Please help!

```
# writes the title as text in the window
titleFont = tkFont.Font(family = "Comic Sans MS", size = 20)
titleText = tkinter.Label(app, text="Gods of This World", font=titleFont)
titleText.pack()

# sets the background image to the games 3 colors (Red, Green, Grey)
C = tkinter.Canvas(app, height=300, width=250)
filename = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/Desktop/Gods of This World/net/godsofthisworld/ui/images/backgroundimage.png")
background_label = tkinter.Label(app, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()
```

Comment: first you run `titleText.pack()` and later `background_label.place()` so it can put `image` above `text` - your `text` can be hidden behind `image`. Put it in different order. BTW: I don't know why you create `Canvas` if you don't use `canvas.create_image()` and `canvas_create_text()`

Comment: ok wait never mind ill use the canvas to add the text so it doesent cover up my image with a grey background.

Answer (score 0):

You put image after text - and you use `.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)` - so text is hidden behind image.

Put it in different order - first image, next text.

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

# first image   
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
background_label = tk.Label(app, image=photo)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# next text   
titleText = tk.Label(app, text="Gods of This World")
titleText.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** `label` with text will have gray background - and you can't remove it. If you want text without background then use `Canvas` and `canvas.create_image()`, `canvas.create_text()` - without `pack()` and `place()`

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

app = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")
canvas.create_image((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), image=photo) #, anchor='center')
canvas.create_text((WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), text="Gods of This World") #, anchor='center')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and now I can work on adding the start game buttons!

Comment: BTW: you can use `canvas.create_window((x, y), window=tk.Button(...), ...)` to put `Button` (or any other widget) on `Canvas`. Doc effbot.org: [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)